# Responsive table where title follows the content

Tags: css, html, html-table

I was wondering if it was possible to make responsive table (responsive meaning that rows break away and go below one another) where `<th>` follows the column.

This is what I have for now, and here is my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Tararan/pen/GQebBd)

The reason why I am not using bootstrap is because I can't access HTML on this particular project so I was hoping that maybe someone here knows how to make `<th>` follow its content

HTML

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Col 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Col 2
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Left content
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur eleifend nisi eu rhoncus. Morbi scelerisque rutrum ipsum, pretium consectetur augue consequat et.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Left content
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur eleifend nisi eu rhoncus. Morbi scelerisque rutrum ipsum, pretium consectetur augue consequat et.
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
       Left content
      </td>
      <td>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris efficitur eleifend nisi eu rhoncus. Morbi scelerisque rutrum ipsum, pretium consectetur augue consequat et.
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

CSS

```
td {
 padding: 20px;
}

@media all and (max-width:768px) {
         tr {    
           display: table-row;  
           width:100%;    
  }               
         td {    
           display: table-row; 
  }  
            th { 
          display: table-row; 
  }
    }
```

Comment: Is that a real table containing tabular data or not?

Comment: No, just regular text. I am trying currently to use absolute position on second th child, I will see if it works

Answer (score 1):

If your data is not tabular data you could use a simplified markup and `Flexbox`

> [Codepen Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQoepb)

On smaller screens the `flex-direction` is `column` and all the titles have an `order` property smaller than all the `div` (so they can appear first)

When the media screen is matched then content is placed horizontally. through `flex-basis` and `flex-wrap` you could wrap the content in rows.

---

**Markup**

```
<main>

  <h2>Title 1</h2>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 1 ... 
  </div>

  <h2>Title 2</h2>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2 ...
  </div>

  <h2>Title 3</h2>
  <div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum 3 ...
  </div>

</main>
```

**CSS**

```
main {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

main > h2 {  order: 1; }
main > div { order: 2; }

@media all and (min-width: 768px) {
  main {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  main > h2,
  main > div { order: 1; }

  main > h2 { flex: 1 0 25%; }
  main > div { flex: 1 0 75%; }

}
```